# How to add months to a custom date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to create a range of six months between two dates.

The first date `frm` is the current date.

I want the second date `till` to be the date six months in the future (i.e. 6 months after `frm`).

Both dates are in this form `20-DEC-15`, where the beginning two digits are the days and the last two are the year.

Any help on how to adjust the `till` date according to the six months difference?

```
frm = new Date();
till = new Date();
var dd = frm.getDate();
var d = till.getDate();
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "JAN";
month[1] = "FEB";
month[2] = "MAR";
month[3] = "APR";
month[4] = "MAY";
month[5] = "JUNE";
month[6] = "JULY";
month[7] = "AUG";
month[8] = "SEPT";
month[9] = "OCT";
month[10] = "NOV";
month[11] = "DEC";
var mm = month[frm.getMonth()]; 
var m = month[till.getMonth()-6];
var yyyy = frm.getFullYear();
var yyy = till.getFullYear();
yyyy = yyyy.toString().substr(2,2);
yyy = yyy.toString().substr(2,2);
frm = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
till = d+'-'+m+'-'+yyy;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand why you're taking this approach.  But there is a native/built-in javascript Date object:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

You'd find this exercise much easier by just creating an instance of one of these and performing your operations on the month specific functions (exp: getMonth()) - just keep in mind those months are zero indexed.

Comment: @Tim i'm aware of it..But i'm trying to do this for a reason..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's date arithmetic. Add six months, check for year rolling, and validate that your till date lands on a day that actually exists. In this case I've left your month array intact as is. And if you're, for example rolling from a month with a 31st to a month without, it will instead use the last day of the month that it lands on (so Dec 31 + 6 months = May 30).
Does that answer your question?

```js
var dt = new Date("Dec 31, 2015"); //Using arg to show date roll. Remove this arg for current client date.


var month = new Array();
month[0] = "JAN";
month[1] = "FEB";
month[2] = "MAR";
month[3] = "APR";
month[4] = "MAY";
month[5] = "JUNE";
month[6] = "JULY";
month[7] = "AUG";
month[8] = "SEPT";
month[9] = "OCT";
month[10] = "NOV";
month[11] = "DEC";


var tmonth = dt.getMonth() + 6 <= 11 ? dt.getMonth() + 6 : dt.getMonth() - 6;
var tyear = dt.getMonth() + 6 <= 11 ? dt.getFullYear() : dt.getFullYear() + 1;

var eom = new Date(tyear, tmonth + 1, 0).getDate(); //get last day of the month
var tday = dt.getDate() > eom ? eom : dt.getDate(); //check if the from day of month > last day of month, use ldom instead if so.


var frm = dt.getDate() + '-' + month[dt.getMonth()] + '-' + dt.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);
var till = tday + '-' + month[tmonth] + '-' + tyear.toString().substr(2, 2);

console.log(frm);
console.log(till);

document.getElementById('frmDate').innerText = frm;
document.getElementById('tillDate').innerText = till;
```

```html
From: <span id="frmDate"></span><br />
To: <span id="tillDate"></span><br />
```

Comment: When you use snippets you should display the result in the snippet!  Otherwise people run it and notice nothing, then they see you've used the console to log this information :-/...not cool!

Comment: @JonH will amend to include that.

Comment: @Mic thank you for your help and time, i really appreciate it !!

Comment: @Mic dear i'm trying to adjust the range to take days, such as 15 days..But it's not correctly adapting to differences in months and years. Any help?

Comment: @mikeb I'll take a look shortly and get back to you.

Comment: @Mic dear, i fixed it..Thanks for replying

Answer (score 1):

Javascript dates can be painful to work with.  Have you considered using a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)?

With moment you can do stuff like:

```
var frm = moment('2014-12-31');             // Dec 31, 2014
var till = moment(frm).add(6, 'month');     // Jun 30, 2015
var jsDate = till.toDate();                 // native js date
```

This way you don't have to write your own date library.  Note that since June only has 30 days, moment picks the last date in June when adding six months to the last day in December.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to build a very simple parser for you.

What does this do?

1. We define two dates, the first one we are basing ourselves on from your own example `10-DEC-15`. Then we pass this value into a parser, whose objective is to extract the month and add 6 months to it.
2. Within the parser, we extract all the relevant information: year, month and day.
3. Then we move onto comparing what this month is numerically, tedious little thing but it's quite clear below how it works (if/else statements). I did use your months array idea and used it in a better way, less code to write :-)
4. Once we know which month it is numerically, we store the value, then add 6 to it, to represent six months.
5. If the value of the months is greater to six, then we do some math and subtract by 12 to get the month in the following year. Example: September = 9, 9 + 6 = 15, 15-12 = 3, which is March. We also need to add 1 to the year, for example 15 to 16.
6. All done right? Yes, then we return the string as it was originally provided to us. First we form the string by using **[join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** and the delimiter character `-`. Second we wrap this string in a Date object and voila!

Any questions? Ask in the comments below.

```js
var date_1 = new Date("10-DEC-15"),
    date_2 = addMonths(date_1, 6);
    
    alert(date_2);

function addMonths(date, addedMonths){
    var year = date.getYear(),
        month = date.getMonth(),
        day = date.getDay(),
        monthsOfTheYear = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUG", "SEPT", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
    
    // Determine the month in numeric form          
    if(month === monthsOfTheYear[1]){
        month = 1;
    }
    else if(month === monthsOfTheYear[2]){
      month = 2;
    }
    else if(month === monthsOfTheYear[3]){
      month = 3;
    }
    else if(month === monthsOfTheYear[4]){
      month = 4;
    }
    else if(month === monthsOfTheYear[5]){
      month = 5;
    }
    else if(month === monthsOfTheYear[6]){
      month = 6;
    }
    else if(month === monthsOfTheYear[7]){
      month = 7;
    }
    else if(month === monthsOfTheYear[8]){
      month = 8;
    }
    else if(month === monthsOfTheYear[9]){
     month = 9;
    }
    else if(month === monthsOfTheYear[10]){
      month = 10;
    }
    else if(month === monthsOfTheYear[11]){
      month = 11;
    }
    else {
       month = 12;
    }
   
     // Add the desired months to the current month
     month = month + addedMonths;
   
     // Identify if this carries over to a new year
     if(month > 12){
         month -= 12;
         year = parseInt(year) + 1;
     }
   
     return [day, month, year].join('-');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let today = new Date(3600000*Math.floor(Date.now()/3600000));

let nbrMonths = 4;

let todayPlusMonths = today.setMonth(today.getMonth() + nbrMonths);// int 

let resulat = new Date(3600000*Math.floor(datePlusMonths/ 3600000));
```

Enjoy :)